# Android Error on Action Bar?

Tags: android

I;m developing an android application to make action bar transparent and put a back button on action bar. When i done the code it is showing stopped working.

My code is

```
public class Song_List extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_song__list);

        ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
                Intent i=new Intent(Song_List.this, MainActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

The log cat is this...

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jithin.myapplication/com.example.jithin.myapplication.Song_List}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
```

Can anyone suggest me a code to make my action bartransparent and show a back buttton on this .. Thank You

Comment: used getSupportActionbar() instead of   getActionBar()

Answer (score 1):

use

```
    getSupportActionBar()
```

instead of

```
    getActionBar()
```

Comment: Shows Error ..The code becomes red (Cannot resolve Method )

Comment: which class are you using 'android.app.ActionBar' or 'android.support.v7.app.ActionBar' for getActionBar() ?

Comment: No just Action Bar

Comment: check imports please and let me know

Comment: Typo: getSupportActionBar has a capital B

Comment: android.app.ActionBar; (This is the imoprt

Comment: AndroidDeveloperTrainee as @F43nd1r said please check for typo mistake

Comment: first try for getSupportActionBar() else update your import with android.support.v7.app.ActionBar for getActionBar()